# Sharing forms between flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask project which allows users to create projects and to upload files to those projects. The URL structure looks something like `/projects/<project_id>/documents/<document_id>`.

My problem was that I was repeating `/projects/` and `/documents/` a lot for all the views that handled projects and documents (a view to list, a view to show, etc. etc.) so I thought that I could make life easier with blueprints. I decided that I could organize my code something like this:

```
app
    projects
        views.py
        forms.py
        __init__.py
    documents
        views.py
        forms.py
        __init__.py
    views.py
    __init__.py
run.py
```

However, there are forms (as well as pluggable views) that are used in both `documents` and `projects`.

My question is, how can I have code in common between my two blueprints? It's also possible that there's a way easier way to implement this (since all I really need is to avoid redundancy in typing out the URL), and I'd love to hear one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can have multiple documents per project and assuming that one document cannot be shared across multiple projects, I would suggest you only create a "Project" Blueprint and put the "Document" under it as a package. Something like:

```
app/
    projects/
        views.py
        forms.py
        __init__.py
        documents/
            views.py
            forms.py
            __init__.py
    views.py
    __init__.py
run.py
```

Now, under Projects/forms.py, you can add all the common code that is also relevant to Documents. Additionally, documents have their own forms.py but that could be very specific only to a document.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting solution. Are blueprints in general the best way of adding automatic url prefixes?